# Converting memset and struct to newer notation

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm taking this C++ program and am trying to replace some of the older structures like memset (which I don't completely understand) and struct with newer language optimized for C++11. The program works as is and I am just trying to further my understanding by playing with the code.

[image]

> "Hike on a Graph" is played on a board on which an undirected graph
>   with colored edges. The graph is complete and has all loops; for any
>   two locations there is exactly one edge (arrow) between them. The
>   arrows are colored. There are three players, and each of them has a
>   piece. At the beginning of the game, the three pieces are in fixed
>   locations on the graph. In turn, the players move their pieces. A move
>   consists of moving one's own piece along an arrow to a new location on
>   the board. The following constraint is imposed on this: the piece may
>   only be moved along arrows of the same color as the arrow between the
>   two opponents' pieces.
>
> In the sixties a one-person variant of the game emerged. In this
>   variant one person moves all the three pieces, not necessarily one
>   after the other, but of course only one at a time. Goal of this game
>   is to get all pieces onto the same location, using as few moves as
>   possible. Find out the smallest number of moves that is necessary to
>   get all three pieces onto the same location, for a given board layout
>   and starting positions.
>
> Input Specification:
>
> The input file contains several test cases. Each test case starts with
>   the number n. Input is terminated by n=0. Otherwise, 1<=n<=50. Then
>   follow three integers p1, p2, p3 with 1<=pi<=n denoting the starting
>   locations of the game pieces. The colors of the arrows are given next
>   as a m×m matrix of whitespace-separated lower-case letters. The
>   element mij denotes the colour of the arrow between the locations i
>   and j. Since the graph is undirected, you can assume the matrix to be
>   symmetrical.
>
> Output Specification:
>
> For each test case output on a single line the minimum number of moves
>   required to get all three pieces onto the same location, or the word
>   "impossible" if that is not possible for the given board and starting
>   locations.
>
> [Example undirected graph for the first two inputs in the example below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U34e6.gif)
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
> 3 1 2 3
> r b r
> b b b
> r b r
> 2 1 2 2
> y g
> g y
> 1 1 1 1
> a
> 2 1 1 1
> a b
> b d
> 2 1 2 2
> a b
> b a
> 2 1 2 2
> a b
> b b
> 2 1 2 2
> b b
> b b
> 2 1 2 2
> b b
> b a
> 3 1 2 3
> a a a
> a a a
> a a a
> 3 1 2 3
> a b a
> b a b
> a b a
> 3 1 2 3
> a b a
> b b b
> a b a
> ```
>
> **Output:**
>
> ```
> 2
> impossible
> 0
> 0
> impossible
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 2
> impossible
> 2
> ```

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int visited[51][51][51];
char arr[51][51];

struct Vertex
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int t;

    //adding default vals to the struct
    Vertex(int p1,int p2,int p3,int d)
    {
        a = p1;
        b = p2;
        c = p3;
        t = d;
    }
};


void bfs (int n, int p1, int p2, int p3)
{
    queue<Vertex> nodes;
    memset(visited,-1,sizeof(visited));
    //int visited[51][51][51] = { -1 };
    nodes.push(Vertex(p1,p2,p3,0));
    visited[p1][p2][p3] = 0;
    //queue traversal
    while(!nodes.empty())
    {
        //dequeue a vertex from queue
        int a = nodes.front().a;
        int b = nodes.front().b;
        int c = nodes.front().c;
        int t = nodes.front().t;
        nodes.pop();
        //now look at all neighbors
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {   
            //if we're looking at the node or the edge we're traveling on isn't the same as color connecting p2 and p3
            if(i == a || arr[a][i] != arr[b][c])
            {
                continue;
            }
            //if point has been looked at
            if(visited[i][b][c] != -1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            //if it hasn't been processed yet do that now
            nodes.push(Vertex(i,b,c,t+1));
            //cout << "p1:t+1=" << t+1 << endl;
            visited[i][b][c] = t+1;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if(i == b || arr[b][i] != arr[a][c])
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(visited[a][i][c] != -1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            nodes.push(Vertex(a,i,c,t+1));
            visited[a][i][c] = t+1;
        }
        for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            if(i == c || arr[c][i] != arr[a][b])
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(visited[a][b][i] != -1)
            {
                continue;
            }
            nodes.push(Vertex(a,b,i,t+1));
            visited[a][b][i] = t+1;
        }
    }
}

int main ( )
{
    char s;
    int n,p1,p2,p3;
    while (cin >> n)    //read in number of nodes
    {
        if(n == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        cin >> p1 >> p2 >> p3;
        //read in the array
        for ( int i = 1; i <= n ; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 1 ; j <= n ; j++ )
            {
                cin >> s;
                arr[i][j] = s;
                //cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
            }
            //cout << endl;
        }

        int soln;
        bool beginCondition = true;
        bfs(n,p1,p2,p3);
        //if the node isn't equal to infinity, set soln to visited node val and iterate.
        for(int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)
        {
            if(visited[i][i][i] != -1)
            {
                //cout << "Visited!" << visited[i][i][i] << endl;
                //cout << "Soln:" << soln << endl;
                if(beginCondition)
                {
                    soln = visited[i][i][i];
                    beginCondition = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    soln = min(soln,visited[i][i][i]);
                }
            }
        }

        if(beginCondition)
        {
            cout << "impossible" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << soln << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `memset`, and what is "old" about `struct`?

Answer (score 1):

### Comments on code

Note this code and this comment say different things

```
memset(visited,-1,sizeof(visited));
//int visited[51][51][51] = { -1 };
```

Every byte in the `visited` is being set to -1. There are multiple bytes in an `int`. If it works you are just getting lucky.

> #### 3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental] Paragraph 7 of n3936
>
> Types bool, char, char16_t, char32_t, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral types. A synonym for integral type is integer type. The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system. [ Example: this International Standard **permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations** for integral types. —end example ]

Why split it up like this:

```
    //dequeue a vertex from queue
    int a = nodes.front().a;
    int b = nodes.front().b;
    int c = nodes.front().c;
    int t = nodes.front().t;
    nodes.pop();
```

Just copy the vertix

```
    vertix v = nodes.front();
    nodes.pop();
```

Arrays are zero indexed in C++

```
    //now look at all neighbors
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
```

SO this is either wrong or looks wierd.

Don't need two phase read:

```
            cin >> s;
            arr[i][j] = s;
```

Can just do:

```
            cin >> rr[i][j];
```

### Algorithm

Basically your code is C.

You should be wrapping state into objects. Your graph is represented by a global

```
char arr[51][51];
```

Sure. But why not have a graph class. Then you can have more than one graph.

Also you search algorithm uses another glboal.

```
int visited[51][51][51];
```

Put this state into another object. Then you can use the `Visitor Pattern` to do your traversal.